# OPC AddItem возвращает ошибку -1073479672

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2008-r2, opc

Использую OPCAutomation в ASP.NET MVC.

Если запускать сайт с ноутбука, то все хорошо - к серверу подключается, группа создается, теги добавляются.

Но вот если развернуть сайт на IIS сервера (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standart), то теги перестают добавляться

```
Group.OPCItems.AddItems(count, ref tagnames, ref cHandles, out sHandles, out errors);
```

На выходе `errors` будет содержать код -1073479672, что означает:

> The item ID doesn't conform to the server's syntax

Как это исправить?

Comment: 1) зря убрали код, по одно строчке сложно судить о проблеме 2) проверьте имя переменой(с opc давно не работал, но текст ошибки вроде как на это намекает)

Comment: Код просто для вида, проблема не в нем, ибо на ноутбуке работает.
В логах SMC нашел "Unable to add item '...' with access path (null)"
Полагаю проблема в самом сервере, но в то же время:
@ Запуск сайта с ноутбука, подключиться к серверу >> OK
@ Запуск сайта напрямую с сервера >> Error

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у вас asp положение в котором вы пытайтесь подключиться к локальному opc серверу. Исходя из этого я бы сначала попробовал локализовать проблему, а именно... 1) Попробуйте надежный opc сервер. Например тестовый от матрикона 2) Попробуйте протестировать свой код в консольной приложении 3) Попробуйте написать нативный код (c++ или delphi) без использования каких либо библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил. В ArchestrA SMC было неверно указано название opcgroup.